# JS mouseover function to not reset while im hovering a specific div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have this small animation that is working, but not as I want, when I hover one of the triangles it brings a div that is hidden, I want the animation to not reset while I am hovering either the triangle or the hidden div, hope I can make me understand.

The animation is the following one:

```js
$(function() {
    $('.arrow-left').mouseover(function() {    
        $('body').stop( true, true ).css('right', 'auto').animate({
            left: 300
        });
        $('#left-content').show();
    });
    $('.arrow-left').mouseleave(function() {
        $('body').stop( true, true ).css('right', 'auto').animate({
            left: 0
        });
        $('#left-content').hide();
    });
    
    $('.arrow-right').mouseover(function() {    
        $('body').stop( true, true ).css('left', 'auto').animate({
                right: 300
            });
        $('#right-content').show();
    });
    $('.arrow-right').mouseleave(function() {
        $('body').stop( true, true ).css('left', 'auto').animate({
             right: 0
   });
        $('#right-content').hide();
    });
});
```

```css
#anim {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  background-image: url("http://i.imgur.com/rxks29H.jpg");
  background-image: no-repeat;
  background-size: 100%;
}
#anim img {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
.arrow-left {
  padding: 5% 15px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  position: absolute;
  width: 14%;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 3;
  top: 30%;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.arrow-right {
  padding: 5% 15px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  position: absolute;
  width: 14%;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 3;
  top: 30%;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.arrow-right h2 {
  font-size: 28px;
  color: #FFF;
}
.arrow-right:hover h2, .arrow-left:hover h2 {
    color: #DDD;
    text-decoration: underline;
}
.arrow-left h2 {
  font-size: 28px;
  color: #FFF;
}
body {
    position: relative;
}

.hide {
    display: none;
}

#left-content {
    left: -300px;
    height: 400px;
    position: absolute;
    top: -30%;
    width: 300px;
}

#right-content {
    right: -320px;
    height: 400px;
    position: absolute;
    top: -30%;
    width: 300px;
}
```

```html
<section id="anim">
  <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fbhc4.png">
  <div class="arrow-right">
    <h2>Scouting For Companies</h2>
      <div id="right-content" class="hide">
          <h3>Right content</h3>
          <p>A paragraph goes here A paragraph goes here</p>
          <p>A paragraph goes here A paragraph goes here</p>
          <p>A paragraph goes here A paragraph goes here</p>
      </div>
  </div>
  <div class="arrow-left">
    <h2>Seeking For Ideas</h2>
      <div id="left-content" class="hide">
          <h3>Left content</h3>
          <p>A paragraph goes here A paragraph goes here</p>
          <p>A paragraph goes here A paragraph goes here</p>
          <p>A paragraph goes here A paragraph goes here</p>
      </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/a6uwrdm9/1/)

Fiddle Thanks to @amir5000

EDIT: it seems that on jsfiddle behaves differently than on my local files, if i open index.html every time i move my mouse the animation resets.

Comment: Please fix the `Fiddle` link.

Answer (score 2):

Use the [mouseenter](https://api.jquery.com/mouseenter/) event instead of mouseover.

```
$(function() {
    $('.arrow-left').mouseenter(function() {
        // ...
    });
});
```

[JSFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/Skateside/a6uwrdm9/2/)

Comment: It still does the same, on the hidden div if i move the mouse, it resets.

Comment: I think I see what you mean. If I'm right, the problem is that the hidden div and the triangle aren't touching so there's a moment when the cursor is over neither of them, causing the animation to reset. To fix that, add some padding to the hidden div so that the elements touch [example](https://jsfiddle.net/Skateside/a6uwrdm9/3/)